# Is possible to use dll compiled in .net(C#) in Windows Store Apps with HTML5?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, window

With VisualStudio is possible to make Windows Store Apps with HTML5, but I would like to know if its possible to use .net dlls in this kind of projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this but the .NET Project needs to be created as a **Windows Runtime Component** rather than a regular **Class Library**. Anything that is `public` in the .NET project will be callable from JavaScript; note that this limits the types of things you can have in your public surface area - they must all be WinRT-compatible types.